# Injectivity of the Differential of Smooth Map

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to answer the following question:

Let $M = \{(x,y)\in \mathbf{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$. Define a smooth or $C^\infty$ function by $f\colon M \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^2$ as $$(x,y)\rightarrow  \left(\frac{y}{1-x^2-y^2}, e^{x^2} \right).$$

a) Find the set $S$ of points $p$ of at which of $f_*{p}$ (the differential) is injective.

b) Prove that $f(S)$ is an open subset of $\mathbf{R}^2$.

For part a), I have done the following:

The differential of the mapping is given by the Jacobian matrix at an arbitrary point p.

I.E.:
$$
f_*{p}= 
\left(
\begin{matrix} \frac{2xy}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}&\frac{1-x^2+y^2}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}\\ 2xe^{x^2}&0\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Since $\operatorname{rank}(f_*{p}) < 2$, from the above then $f$ fails to be an immersion. Since the Jacobian is $2\times 2$, we can just take the determinant and check when it equals zero and by the I.F.T (the Inverse function Theorem), we see that:

$\det (f_*{p}) = -2xe^{x^2}\frac{1-x^2+y^2}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}$ , and when this equals zero, you would get $x=0$, or $y=\pm 1$. To then conclude what set $S$ for which the differential is injective, then I conclude that $S = M \setminus \{(0,y): y \in  (-1,1)\}$. I hope that this is enough...

b) I am a bit stuck on this one, to be honest. First I try to find f{(0,y): y$\epsilon$ (-1,1)}, which is part of what I found in part a). For that, I would get: {($\frac{y}{(1-y^2)^2}$,1)}=(-$\infty$,$\infty$)x{1}, which is itself a subset of $R^2$. I am then trying to apply the following logic: f(S) = f(M - (-$\infty$,$\infty$)x{1})$\supset$f(M)-f($\infty$,$\infty$)x{1}), but am not sure how this even helps.

Any feedback, particularly on part b), is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: $f$ is invertible on $S$ and the inverse is smooth.

Comment: @Chilango- Can you please explain how this helps?

Comment: If you compute $S$ correctly, I think you will find it is open. Then, the  [inverse function theorem](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1097014.files/InvImp.pdf) gives you an inverse mapping which is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the argument above, one can use the observation that:

$f(M)= ${$ (x,y)\epsilon$$R^2 1$$\leq$$y$$<$e }.

it is clear then that $f(S) =${$ (x,y)\epsilon$$R^2 1$$<$$y$$<$e }

which is an open set in $R^2$.